# jQuery datepicker not allowing to select date when page is scrolled

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I came across a strange defect in our application for IE 11 browser. We are using jQuery datepicker.

Steps to reproduce are:

1. Click on icon of datepicker to open
2. Instead of selecting date scroll the page
3. try to select any date; on first click date is not getting selected.

Just need some pointers on this. Is it a jQuery datepicker bug or IE 11 issue. My first thought is datepicker is losing focus and first click is to get the focus on datepicker.

Please suggest what you think.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jbK6a/15/

Comment: https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8403 ; this is the issue